# Incorrect dates on screenshots taken on Galaxy Nexus i9250

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, files, screenshots, date-and-time

I have first Nexus ([Galaxy Nexus i9250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus)) with Android 4.3 on-board. I've been making screenshots of the screens, I'm seeing, for as long, as I have this phone (nearly three years) and there were always no problems with anything.

I made a two series of screenshots recently. First batch was made on last Saturday (two days ago, `2015-03-22`) and second one yesterday (`2015-03-23`). I have just downloaded all screenshots to my PC, and to my surprise, I noticed, that screenshots made two days ago have all dates since middle of `2004-01` till end of that month. And all screenshots made yesterday have dates around `2005-08`.

[image]

What am I missing. Is my phone going crazy after three months of using it?

BTW: This is [second strange thing](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/103309/20449), that happens to my phone during past week. Is my Nexus getting too old? :> And should I start to think of replacing it? Are smartphone meant to run over three years? :>

Comment: Is the date set correctly on the phone? How are you copying the files?

Comment: Date is auto-updated basing on SIM carrier cellar network data, so yes -- it is up to date. Files are copied using microUSB cable, over stupid-like-a-hell MTP protocol.